# Vba If Sheet Not/found then create/append data

Tags: excel, vba

Newbie alert. I created a code which I want to look for a sheet, and create one if it's not found. If it exists, I want it to run another routine.

VBA successfully creates a new sheet and pastes all data if there is no sheet, however when run again it tries to add a sheet instead of going to the procedure for when the sheet already exists.

I looked at 20+ questions on stack overflow and elsewhere and almost all of them look for a Boolean value of whether a sheet exists, which is not what I want, so hopefully this is not a duplicate.

My reasoning is that when I run CheckAndAppend and the sub cannot .Select the NewSht, it errors and goes to AddSht and finishes.

The second time I run this, the sheet exists, so it should just perform the CheckAndAppend without going to AddSht, which I thought I could achieve by putting "Exit sub". This is not happening.

My code is as follows

```
Sub CheckAndAppend()
Dim wbCtrl As Workbook
Dim sCurrPeriod As String
Dim Lastrw As Long
Dim NewSht As Variant

Set wbCtrl = Workbooks("Transactions_Convert.xlsm")
sCurrPeriod = wbCtrl.Worksheets("Control").Range("Period")
NewSht = "UK" & sCurrPeriod & "loaded"

'Create a new sheet to store the loaded data if doesn't exist

On Error GoTo AddSht
'CheckAndAppend - perform this when the sheet exists (copy data from Duplicates Sheet, find last row on NewSht and append).
    wbCtrl.Activate
    Sheets("UK_Duplicates_Check").Select
    Range("A2:K" & Row.Count).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(NewSht).Select
    Lastrw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(LastRow, 1).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Local:=True
    Exit Sub

AddSht:
'Add sheet if it doesn't exist
wbCtrl.Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = NewSht
    Sheets("UK_Duplicates_Check").Select
    Columns("A:K").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(NewSht).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested so try on a copy of your workbook first but does what you're looking for

```
Sub CheckAndAppend()
    Dim wbCtrl As Workbook
    Dim NewSht As Worksheet
    Dim sCurrPeriod As String, NewShtname As String
    Dim Lastrw As Long

    Set wbCtrl = Workbooks("Transactions_Convert.xlsm")
    sCurrPeriod = wbCtrl.Worksheets("Control").Range("Period")
    NewShtname = "UK" & sCurrPeriod & "loaded"
    ' Test if shet exists
    On Error Resume Next
    Set NewSht = wbCtrl.Sheets(NewShtname)
    On Error GoTo 0
    ' If sheet doesn't exist create
    If NewSht Is Nothing Then
        Set NewSht = wbCtrl.Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(wbCtrl.Count))
        NewSht.Name = NewShtname
    End If
    ' Copy source
    With wbCtrl.Sheet("UK_Duplicates_Check")
        .Range("A2:K" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
    End With
    ' Paste to destination
    With NewSht
        .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial local:=True
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the error to decide if a sheet is to be added or not, but any error will trigger that event and add a sheet.
It is also better not to activate or select sheets, but reference them directly like this copy and paste

```
Sheets("UK_Duplicates_Check").Range("A:K").Copy Sheets(NewSht).Range("A1")
```

try this:

```
Sub CheckAndAppend()
Dim wbCtrl As Workbook
Dim sCurrPeriod As String
Dim Lastrw As Long
Dim NewSht As Variant

Set wbCtrl = Workbooks("Transactions_Convert.xlsm")
sCurrPeriod = wbCtrl.Worksheets("Control").Range("Period")
NewSht = "UK" & sCurrPeriod & "loaded"

itshere = 0
For Each ws In Excel.Worksheets    'check if worksheet exists without giving an error
    If ws.Name = NewSht Then
        itshere = 1
        Exit For
    End If
Next

If itshere = 0 Then
'Add sheet
wbCtrl.Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
    ActiveSheet.Name = NewSht
    Sheets("UK_Duplicates_Check").Select
    Columns("A:K").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(NewSht).Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
Else
'perform this when the sheet exists (copy data from Duplicates Sheet, find last row on NewSht and append).
    wbCtrl.Activate
    Sheets("UK_Duplicates_Check").Select
    Range("A2:K" & Rows.Count).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets(NewSht).Select
    Lastrw = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(LastRw, 1).Offset(1, 0).Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Local:=True
End If
End Sub
```